# mapDispatchToProps to be explicit

Tags: reactjs, redux

In react/redux I'm trying to convert this `mapDispatchToProps` to be explicit:

`const mapDispatchToProps = { createOrganization }`

I tried this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    createOrganization: (organization) => {
      dispatch(createOrganization(organization))
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the action

```
export const createOrganization = (organization) => ({
  type: ACTION_CREATE_ORGANIZATION,
  payload: api.createOrganization(organization),
})
```

But It's nor working. What can I do? Am I missing something?

The error is "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined". What it's happening is that once I enter a code, it should create an organization and redirect me to the page /dashboard, but it's not working

```
  handleClick = (e, formData) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (formData.betaCode && formData.organization && this.props.userData) {
      this.props.createOrganization({
        name: formData.organization,
        owner: {
          id: this.props.userData.id,
          name: this.props.userData.login,
          ownerAvatar: this.props.userData.avatar_url
        },
        beta_code: formData.betaCode

      })
      .then(() => {
        this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: `const mapDispatchToProps = { createOrganization }` should be okay, if you pass it as a second parameter into `connect`

Comment: yes, is correct but I need to change it to be explicit (we are refactoring the code), @TheReason but it's not working

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: I updated the question to show the error @TheReason

Comment: @EricHasselbring I updated the question to show the error :)

Comment: That's because of `createOrganization` doesn't return a promise.

Comment: So what should I do? @TheReason

Comment: in your action from your call to the api, you can just return the response which should be a promise if you are using a library such as Axios. If you are not making an api call then its synchronous, so you shouldn't need the then

Comment: @EricHasselbring is right. @Liz `createOrganization` should be sync or async?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, `createOrganization` action should be an *async*. Something similar to:

```
const = createOrganization = organization => dispatch =>
  api.createOrganization(organization)
    .then(
      response => dispatch({ type: ACTION_CREATE_ORGANIZATION, payload: response}),
      error => dispatch({ type: ACTION_CREATE_ORGANIZATION_ERROR, payload: error}),
    )
```

But it's not enough, you should install [`redux-thunk`](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) && [`redux-promise`](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-promise) to handle such kind of action.

Rest of your code shouldn't be changed. Then you will be able to use `mapDispatchToProps` as you want:

`const mapDispatchToProps = { createOrganization }`

Hope it make sense. [`Async`](https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) flow in redux